# How to encrypt a number larger than N on RSA?

Tags: python, ios, encryption, rsa, public-key-encryption

Here is an example:

p = 11, q = 5, N = p*q = 55, choose encryption exponent e = 3, so d = e^-1 mod (p-1)(q-1) = 27.

If I want encrypt x=13, x^e=13^3=52mod55.

I understand how to encrypt a number which is less than N, but how to encrypt a number which is larger than N?

I know if X is larger than N, we should decompose X into several parts and encrypt them respectively, but I don't know how RSA decompose it?

Optional question:

How to encrypt a file with RSA on IOS or python?

Comment: increase q?   If N = p*q, if you've set p then q must be the only thing left you can increase.

Comment: @cjb110 p and q are fixed, I think the only way is to decompose X, but I don't know how RSA does it.

Comment: weird, I can't see how if p & q are both fixed, and N is a limit that you can change that limit in anyway without altering either p or q.  wait, that e/d formula will have multiple solutions so you 'pick' a bigger d or e?

Comment: @cjb110 It's me make them fixed... Because X may be several thousand bits long, I shouldn't choose p or q based on how long X is.

Comment: Try to write `x` in base `n`. Then encrypt each of these "digits".

Comment: @Bakuriu It'll cost lots of time to decompose x base n if x is a long long number. As data is binary in memory, let's say n is m bit length, maybe I can decompose x into parts each is m-1 bit. Now I'm look for an implementation of RSA to check it.

Comment: @KudoCC No, it's pretty fast: `while number: yield number % base; number //= base`. Done. It takes `log(n)` steps (where `log` is logarithm in the given base).

Comment: @Bakuriu You're right when number range within cpu word length, it can do division in one intruction. If number is n bits length, n would be one thousand or more, the division and modulo operation take polynomial time. I'd like to talk analysis of algorithm because I am reading <Algorithms> these days.

Comment: @KudoCC Conversion to a different base is one of the *fastest* operations you can do. If you think you cannot afford it due to efficiency I recommend buying a magic wand, because RSA exponentiation takes *much* more time...

Comment: @Bakuriu Yeah, RSA is time-consuming, but I want to know how RSA decomposes the original data... We are guessing...

Comment: @KudoCC RSA does **not** decompose anything! RSA is about encrypting *a* single integer which is at most `N-1`. To encrypt bigger messages using RSA *you* have to decompose the message into a certain number of integers satisfying RSA assumptions. Converting to base `N` is *one*, very simple, way of achieving what you want. Anyway, since your question is only about cryptography, it would be more on-topic on [cryptography.SE](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @Bakuriu Oh!!! I understand!!! So RSA tells nothing about how to decompose a large number... Great job, thank you.

Comment: @KudoCC Consider reading [Block cipher mode of operation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation). It explains how, *once you have defined how to split your message*, you can *safely* encrypt it. If you thought that you should just use RSA separately on each piece, well, that's the *wrong* way of encrypting.

Comment: @Bakuriu Thanks, I will reading it but I must sleep now...

Comment: @Bakuriu Consider writing your answer down. :)

Comment: You should use hybrid encryption. Chose a random AES key, encrypt the actual message with AES and the AES key with RSA. The AES key will be much smaller than N.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You don't** use RSA to encrypt long messages.

The correct approach is using [hybrid encryption](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hybrid_cryptosystem) instead:

- Generate a random AES key, encrypt the actual data with AES. Preferably using an authenticated mode like AES-GCM.
- Encrypt the AES key with RSA. This key (126 to 256 bits) is small enough to fit within one RSA block. For example using small and thus weak 1024 bit RSA keys you have 500-700 bits for the actual data (the rest is consumed by the padding).
- The ciphertext consists of both the RSA encrypted AES key and the AES encrypted file.

  It's essential for security to apply padding here, namely [OAEP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimal_asymmetric_encryption_padding). Most other paddings, including the popular PKCS#1v1.5 padding are not secure.

Don't try to split the file into blocks which you encrypt with RSA. There are no standard ways for doing this, because it's a bad idea.

Answer (score 2):

The RSA algorithm does *not* handle decomposition of the message at all. It just encrypts fixed-size integers. This kind of encryption algorithms is called a [block cipher](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher), because it encrypts messages in fixed-size "blocks".

How the blocks are obtained is generally not specified by the block-cipher itself. So, *you* have to decide how to split the message. One of the possible ways to decompose an integer into fixed-size blocks is to convert it to base `N`, and encrypt each digit separately.

Note that you should *not* encrypt each digit *independently* from the others, because that wouldn't be safe. In fact doing so is equivalent to using a monoalphabetic cipher. . There are different mode of operations for block ciphers that you can use to safely encrypt multiple blocks. You should read the [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Cipher-block_chaining_.28CBC.29) page to learn about them.

Comment: You shouldn't really call RSA a block-cipher. It's asymmetric and the message is smaller than the ciphertext thanks to padding.

Comment: @CodesInChaos I'm referring to "plain RSA" (as the OP does, since he isn't mentioning padding for example). See how [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_%28cryptosystem%29#Padding) distinguish the "plain" version from what is actually used. Surely we generally speak of block ciphers with symmetric encryption, but I just wanted to point out a more general concept of how to handle encryption when you have to split the input in blocks.

Comment: You still should not use block cipher modes of operation with textbook RSA. They'd be unbelievably broken or would not work at all. These modes are designed with a pseudo random permutation in mind.

Comment: Hi, I want to let you know I am making a hard decision. There is no doubt that you solved my question and make me understand what rsa don't do, it's really helpful to me. But CodesInChaos point to the right way, his point is right to encrypting a file. It may be appropriate to accept his answer, it may help others. Thanks to your great answer again!!!!!